# implement joomla 3 registration field with jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-ui, joomla3.0

i want to implement a field with jquery autocomplete

the code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script>
      $(function() {
        var codice = [
          "b012198",
          "b989000",
          "l928981",
          "f987651",
          "t567342",
          "b865431",
          "l543215",
          "t100543",
          "b544563",
          "f544321"
        ];
        $( "#enter" ).autocomplete({
          source: codice
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
 
    <div class="ui-widget">
      <label for="enter">Codice : </label>
      <input id="enter">
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

and that works.

i want to callback this in a registration field in joomla 3.4 
I called this field 'codice' and it's an element of php array fields of the user-profile.

which files have to change in joomla? what function should be use?